# Routes unable to load using react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm designing a simple application using `create-react-app` and I've recently delved into the power of `react-router`. However, I'm having an issue with pages getting stuck trying to load, and I'm not sure why.

I've got a Navbar component, for which I'll condense the gist of what it is.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import BlogPost from '../Pages/BlogPost';

// Condensed because a lot of the detail is unnecessary and no-one likes blocks of unneeded code
class Navbar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <nav>
          <div id="navigationlinks">
            <ul id="navlinks-left">
                <li className="nav-item"><Link to='/'>Home</Link></li>
              <li className="nav-item"><Link to='/about'>About</Link></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>

        <Switch>
          <Route path='/post' component={BlogPost} />
          <Route path='/about'>
            <About />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

function About() {
  return <h2>The about page.</h2>;
}

export default Navbar;
```

`BlogPost` represents a component that is a page in itself. The code looks like this. Again, I'll abstract away from the stuff that's not relevant.

```js
import React from 'react';

import Navbar from '../Components/Navbar';
// Other components on this page. None of them reference the navbar or contain a router of their own.
import BlogBox from '../Sections/BlogBox';
import CommentForm from '../Components/CommentForm';
import CommentBox from '../Sections/CommentBox';

class BlogPost extends React.Component {
    
    getBlogPost(address) {
        // Gets blog data (like the title, description, content, image, etc.) using 'fetch' from 
        // an API at 'address'. Abstracted away because this isn't relevant.
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("Blog post mounted!");
        this.getBlogPost("http://localhost:8080/api/blog/samplepost");
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="blog-post">
                <Navbar />
                <BlogBox post={this.state ? this.state.post : ""}/>
                <CommentForm />
                <CommentBox comments={this.state ? this.state.comments: ""} />
            </div>
        );
    }   

}

export default BlogPost;
```

The homepage of my application is located at `'/'`. It's rendered in my `index.js` file, the code of which is below.

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import BlogHome from './Pages/BlogHome';
import BlogPost from './Pages/BlogPost';

ReactDOM.render(
    <BlogHome />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

The homepage renders fine, but when I go to navigate to `/post`, the application attempts to load the page indefinitely, and eventually times out, being unable to do so.

Notice how the `BlogPost` page component renders the `Navbar` component, which in turn has a path `/post` which renders the `BlogPost` object? I'm not sure if I'm able to change this. Could this be the reason why the `/post` path can't load?

What concerns me the most here is that I eventually would like to add additional pages which will not only contain this same `Navbar`, but for which their page links also exist in this Navbar. For example, if I add an **About** page, this page will not only contain the Navbar, but its link will also be present in this Navbar!

Is there a way I can keep such self-page links in the Navbar, without the recursive render loop occurring?

Comment: That is probably exactly why it times out, seems you've created a recursive render loop. What and where is the "home" route rendered? I.E. what is rendering a `<Route path="/" component={???} />`? Why do you render your `NavBar` again? Typically that would be rendered outside the routes it navigates to.

Comment: @DrewReese Excellent questions. I've updated the question to include the code in my `index.js` file. The `BlogHome` component also contains the `Navbar` object, but it renders fine, probably due to the fact that there is no `Route` which currently serves the base path `/`.

Comment: As for why I've re-rendered the `Navbar` object, I usually render it at the top of every page in my application (as is usually typically for a navbar). Thus, I thought that I could incorporate `react-router` into this component, seeing as it will exist on every page, but this may be a rookie mistake, due to the recursive loop you mentioned. It would be nice, however, to be able to use my `Navbar` (somehow) incorporated with `react-router`, if possible..

Comment: So you've not only rendered your `Navbar` in multiple places, but also `BlogPost`? A navbar at the top of each page is fine, but you're rendering more than just navigation links. You create a cycle.

Comment: `BlogPost` is currently only "rendered" in 1 place, and that is as a top-level page component which is intended to be routed to at the `/post` route. Or at least, I'm trying to render it in only 1 place... I'm not sure if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

You are creating a cycle between rendering `Navbar` and `BlogPost` when the current path matches "/post`.

In other words `BlogHome` renders a `Navar` which renders a `BlogPost` which then renders another `Navbar` and another `BlogPost` ad nauseam.

## Solution

Restructure your navbar and routes a bit to split them out

index.js

Since `BlogHome` sounds like a page it should be placed on its own route. Move `Router` here to wrap entire app. Render `BlogHome` path last as that matches all path prefixes, so it will render if no other route is matched above it by the `Switch`.

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/post' component={BlogPost} />
        <Route path='/about'>
          <About />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/" component={BlogHome} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Navbar

Remove the router and routes, leave links only.

```
class Navbar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <nav>
        <div id="navigationlinks">
          <ul id="navlinks-left">
              <li className="nav-item"><Link to='/'>Home</Link></li>
            <li className="nav-item"><Link to='/about'>About</Link></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}
```

Now each page should be free to render a `Navbar` or not.

Comment: I think your answer helped me to grasp some of the core concepts behind `react-router` that I didn't understand before - maybe you can help me clarify one of these concepts. By "rendering" a `Router` in the `index.js` file, are we simply setting up a route "fork" which will read the current path and render the corresponding component based on the switch? I previously thought that you could only pass rendered components into the `ReactDOM.render()` function.

Comment: @AnagramDatagram You pass JSX to `ReactDOM.render`. Previously you rendered `<BlogHome />` into it, in my example a `<Router>...</Router>` is rendered into it. The `Router` renders its children, one of which is a `Switch` that renders `Route` components. If by "fork" you mean *some logic branching* then I supposed you could think about the `Switch` component as such since it renders routes exclusively (as opposed to inclusively with `Router`). Anything that is valid renderable JSX can be rendered into `ReactDOM.render`.

Comment: Wonderful. Clear and detailed explanations, and the solution you provided works perfectly and as I wanted. This will definitely pave the way for the next steps I have this application. Thank you!

Comment: Coming to this question from the future to help people who may be having the same problem; I was able to keep all router components together by rendering the Navbar at the top level, keeping the `Link` and `Switch` components together. This keeps the Navbar at the top of every page (which isn't a problem for me), and renders each page component (not containing the navbar) below it.

Answer (score 0):

try to remove Navbar in your BlogPost component, because when the location changes it will switch component here

```js
   <Switch>
      <Route path='/post' component={BlogPost} />
      <Route path='/about'>
        <About />
      </Route>
   </Switch>
```

and

```js
   <nav>
      <div id="navigationlinks">
          <ul id="navlinks-left">
                <li className="nav-item"><Link to='/'>Home</Link></li>
            <li className="nav-item"><Link to='/about'>About</Link></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </nav>
```

will persisit.